# Projective coordinates for elliptic curves

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

If we consider an elliptic curve projectively, it is a homogeneous form in $3$ variables say $x$, $y$ and $z$. How is this related to the Thue equations (homogeneous forms in $2$ variables)?

I'm looking for any information on how Thue's theorem can be generalized to equations of the form f(x,y,z) = A where f is a homogeneous form and futhermore if this may be related to Mordells' Theorem since an elliptic curve is such a homogeneous form in 3 variables (when considered in projective coordinates).

Comment: Please share  your thoughts on this problem, or you will not like it here.

Comment: Don, well I'm looking for any information on how Thue's theorem can be generalized to equations of the form f(x,y,z) = A where f is a homogenous form and futhermore if this may be related to Mordells' Theorem since an ellptic curve is such a homogenous form in 3 variables (when considered in projective coordinates).

Comment: How can we apply Mordells' Theorem here?

Comment: Don, I'm more looking into how I can apply Thues theorem (or similr) to get Mordell's Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

This generalisation of Thue's equation to ternary forms is well-known, see for example the article [*Ternary Form Equations*](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~beuke106/ternaryforms.pdf) by F. Beukers (2007). There in particular the case $T(x,y,z)=1$ in the integral unknowns $x,y,z$ is considered.